# How to determine antenna noise power?

Tags: rf, physics, ham-radio

For a 1.4 GHz radio telescope project I'm working on, I need to know the power level of noise an outdoor dipole antenna will be outputting in order to determine the amount of amplification needed. Most probably I'll end up using a variable gain amplifier to fine-tune the amplification but it would certainly help to have a ballpark estimate.

I guess this is something most RF engineers will have to consider, but I couldn't find any concrete information on it.
To my knowledge the noise is partly internally generated and partly picked up from ambient/sun/astronomical RF noise.

Is there any rule of thumb for estimating the noise temperature of an antenna?
What factors does it depend on (i.e. physical antenna temperature, antenna type, frequency, etc.)?

Comment: What you should be more concerned about I think, is the SNR, that is Signal to Noise Ratio.

Comment: @Dzarda it's a _Radio_ telescope antennae, he needs to know the noise floor.  The objects that he is looking can't saturate the receiver.

Comment: @Dzarda That is true and, in part, why I'ld like to know the noise power. I am aware that the SNR is going to be horrible, but this is an intrinsical property of radio telescopes. I'll be averaging billions of 1-bit samples from two independent receivers so as to improve the SNR and get rid of signals they don't share, that is internal noise.

Comment: @placeholder Yes, my bad.

Comment: I know nothing about antenna's.  (You might want to look up Penias and Wilson and see how they tracked down their antenna noise.)  But if you can model your antenna as an LCR circuit, then it should be fairly easy.  And yes it will depend on temperature, the R part in LCR, and if there is much of a resonance.  (is there any antenna Q?)  There is a fun fact that comes out of the equi-partition theorem, that says for a given capacitance C the total V^2 noise will be kT/C (where k is Boltzmann's constant.).. independent of the resistance in the circuit.

Comment: What are you looking at? If you're going to be looking at CMBR, you will **have** to cryogenically cool your front-end amplifiers to get the noise low enough. I work in an astrophysics lab that builds these things. Personally, I mostly do back-end electronics and data-acquisition, but I have  coworkers who I can ask for more bizarre front-end stuff. Ask me anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dipole is not very directional even if you pointed it upwards; 99% of the noise it will pick up is terrestrial hence the noise temperature is that of the earth. If you were using a dish and high frequencies and pointed it at the stars then the noise temperature would be a few tens of Kelvin assuming that your head antenna amplifier was very very good.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_noise_temperature) is short but sweet. [Another](http://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/faculty/nikolova/antenna_dload/current_lectures/L07_Noise.pdf) interesting pdf article. [Here's](http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/temperature.php) another. I quickly scanned thru [this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee252/handouts/antenna_noise.pdf) and it seems useful. Basically i searched "antenna noise temperature" and the first four links appear to be excellent.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Are you suggesting that the noise temperature of the antenna (ignoring the front end) is independent of the physical temperature of the antenna?
This would mean noise temperature is primarily due to external noise and internal brownian noise is negligible. Is that correct?

Comment: It's not as black and white as that but a good approximation.

Comment: Thanks, that is really interesting... Could you kindly point me to some further reading?
Also, why 'a few tens of Kelvin'? Are you referring to CMB? Or does this include all sorts of sources?

Comment: The wiki is nice, the second is semi OK. (I always thought noise power was 4kT/Hz) Emmisivity and black body radiation are old friends...but I hate when they fold everything into an "effective temperature"  all the physics gets lost in the equations.

Comment: Space is 3-4K, but you need cooled amplifiers to resolve that.

Comment: Also, you generally do need at least partially cooled antennas to resolve CMB radiation. The systems I work with used uncooled parabolic primary and secondary mirrors, but a cooled corrugated horn in a cryogenic dewar as the actual feed-horn, coupled to cryogenicly cooled front-end amplifiers. The horn is cooled to ~70-80K, and the amplifiers to ~10-20K using a [cryocooler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryocooler#GM-refrigerators).

Comment: Well, I guess you can probably at least resolve CMBR without a cooled detector. I may be somewhat biased since the equipment I'm around is seeking to do high-precision measurements.

Comment: @connor wow that sounds really interesting. I would say cool but that would be trite lol. What sort of organization are you working for. I understand if you can't say.

Comment: @Andyaka - Nah, nothing spectacular there. I work for a UCSB Astrophysics lab. It's just research. Really, I don't know *that* much about the actual science behind all the experiments, I just work on the stuff that lets the actual science people do their stuff.

Comment: @Connor sounds really interesting though!

Comment: It's certainly a great way to get to play with liquid nitrogen. Or sit next to [one of these things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvI9exLnXxE) until it drives you insane.

Comment: @ConnorWolf - it reminds me of when I used to design the electrics for gas mass spectrometers many years ago. I was astounded at how damn sensitive they could be.

Comment: Oh, it's not that they're sensitive, it's that they sound like a unlubricated (hur hur) robot trying to jerk off continuously, loudly. They may have been colloquially called "mechasturbators".

Comment: @ConnorWolf \$(LOL)^3\$

Comment: They make a distinct "Sss\$KRUN\$k...sss Sss\$KRUN\$k...sss Sss\$KRUN\$k...sss" noise at about 1-2 Hz, as the displacement piston shuttles helium back and forth in the cold-head. It's a very distinct sound. The link above has the sound. The added whistling noise is probably because the cold-head isn't down to temperature yet.